# MySQL datatype conversion from varchar to float

Tags: mysql

How might I convert a `varchar` into a `float` in MySQL while executing a query?

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html, use CAST, but make sure your content strings are convertable to float.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cannot cast the value in mysql using float type.

The type can use following values:

- BINARY[(N)]
- CHAR[(N)]
- DATE
- DATETIME
- DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
- SIGNED [INTEGER]
- TIME
- UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

So in your case you have to use decimal, e.g:

```
select cast(amount AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as 'float-value' from amounts
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use this simple trick `0 + column_name` to convert it to float.

```
select 0 + column_name from table;
```

Comment: Amazing! Nice trick. It's compact, and doesn't need to assume any specific amount of numbers past the decimal.

Comment: Correct answer!