# MySQL Data type calculated field

Tags: mysql, casting, decimal, case

I am trying to use a case statement with a decimal, and to have the result also be a decimal.  I am using the below statement as an example.  In my table, `myDollar` is a decimal, but here, 'newDollar' is a `varChar`.  I have tried using cast and I can't figure out where/how to use it here.

```
select tab.*,
    case when flag = '1'
        then (myDollar * .525)
            else '0' end as newDollar
                from `xxx` tab;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try without quotes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005445/mysql-datatype-conversion-from-varchar-to-float

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278733/converting-varchar-to-decimal-values-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that MySQL will perform computations in double precision floating point unless you coerce it, try this. Notice that the `0` in `else 0` doesn't have quotation marks around it. That's because you want a numeric value, not a character value.

```
SELECT CAST(case when flag = '1' then (myDollar * 0.525)
                                 else 0 end
            AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as newDollar
```

Comment: Thank you!  This makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using IF ?

```
select *,
if (`flag` = '1', `myDollar` * 0.525 , 0.0) as newDollar
            from `tab`;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Looks much cleaner, for some reason I choose case -_-

Comment: @kenznpunky don't forget to flag "solved" you subject if it's ok ;)

Comment: Oh, thank you!  Didn't realize I should do that - :)