# How do i save an C# float to an Mysql float?

Tags: c#, mysql

I can't find any solution, how to save an float in c# to mysql. It save's only the integer.
If my float is for example 2.5 and i save it into my table, than there it's a 2.

I changed the type to double, but i got the same result.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: What does your query look like? Are you using parameters? Show some code!

Comment: What does the column definition look like?

Answer (score 0):

you can use type of

```
DECIMAL
```

some information you can get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005445/mysql-datatype-conversion-from-varchar-to-float%22this%22)

Answer (score 0):

This is my SQL Command:

```
 using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(sqlConnString.GetConnectionString(true)))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string SQLString = @"INSERT INTO account_components 
                                (accountID,shapeMother,shapeFather,skinMother,skinFather,shapeMix,skinMix,
                                eyeColor,eyeBrows,lipstick,lipstickColor,beard,beardColor,
                                hair,hairColor) VALUES
                                ('" + _acc.Id + "'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.ShapeMother + "'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.ShapeFather + "'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.SkinMother + "'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.SkinFather + "'," +
                                "'@ShapeMix'," +
                                "'@SkinMix'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.EyeColor + "'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.EyeBrows + "'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.Lipstick + "'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.LipstickColor + "'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.Beard + "'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.BeardColor + "'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.Hair + "'," +
                                "'" + _acc.Character.HairColor + "')";

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLString, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("ShapeMix", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = 0.5f; //_acc.Character.ShapeMix;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("SkinMix", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = 0.5f; //_acc.Character.SkinMix;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        } //connection closed and disposed here
    }
```

And this is my database: [Database Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnyF0.png)